# How to solve facebook login problem on Magento?

Tags: api, login, ce-1.9.2.2, facebook

I use facebook login module in magento site that not redirecting to my Magento 1.9.2 site.
But i user this module many Magento 1.9.2 site that are rediredted succesfully with account My Dashboard.

I think it is my domain server configuration issue.

How can i findout what actual problem of my server domain configuarion.

Module Url:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/twitter-facebook-login-by-plumrocket-inc.html

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have faced might have been caused by Magento settings or by third-party extensions you might have installed. For example, there can be an issue with JS-scripts, which correspond for popup display and redirects. You may also have turned off the display of the errors notification and that is the reason why you see white page but not the error text. Our team will gladly help you in solving this issue, if you contact our support service https://store.plumrocket.com/contacts/

*Disclosure: I am a developer at Plumrocket Inc*

Comment: Hey @plumrocket thanks for joining our community! This answer seems to be okay but be careful not to use SE for your product promotion on a repeated basis. Thanks!

Comment: it work for me , there fb app issue that solved problem

Comment: @matinict I'm happy to hear that your problem has been solved.